# AmCharts Pie Chart counter-clockwise

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I have created a [pie chart with AmCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/pie-chart/) but can't seem to find how to display the series values in an anti-clockwise direction.

From the documentation I can see there is are [startAngle](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/piechart/#startAngle_property) (default -90) and [endAngle](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/piechart/#endAngle_property) (default 270) properties, but I can't see how to either use these, or another property so that the values are added in the other direction.

Comment: If by counter-clockwise you mean that the slices should come in reverse order than they are in data, you can just reverse your data: `chart.data.reverse()`

Comment: Hi @martynasma - I don't mean the order of the segments / data, but rather how they appear in the chart. At the moment the first segment is at the 12 o'clock position filling in a clockwise direction towards 1 o'clock / 2 o'clock etc. I would like the chart to start at 12 o'clock, but fill the segments counter-clockwise - going towards 11 o'clock, 10 o'clock etc. Is this possible?